# Talk to server on docker container with no exposed ports

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have some docker containers talking together through docker bridge networks. They cannot be accessed from outside (I was said) as they are launched from a script with a default command which does not include 'expose' nor '-p' option. I cannot change that script.

I would like to connect to one of this containers which runs a server and listens for requests on port 8080. I tried connecting that bridge to a newly created docker bridge network, but i did not succede.
Now I am thinking of creating a new container and letting it talk to the server one (through bridge networks). As it is a new contaienr I can use the 'expose' or '-p' options, so it would be able to talk to the host machine.

Is it a good idea? How can I forward every request made to that container to the server one and get responses back to the host machine then?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the container to which you are trying to connect is an http server, you may be able to use a ready-made container image that can work as an http forwarder (e.g., nginx - it is relatively easy to configure it as an http forwarder).

If you need plain tcp forwarding, you could make a container running 'socat' (socat can work as a tcp forwarder).

NOTE: in either case, you will be exposing a listener that wasn't meant to be on a public address. Do take measures not to allow unauthorized connections.

Answer (score 2):

Within the default docker network, all ports are exposed. So you only need a container that exposes a port to the host machine and is in the same network as the other containers you have already created.

This is a relatively normal pattern. You can use a reverse proxy like nginx to achieve something like this.

There are some containers that automate this process:

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

If you have no control over the other containers though, you will need to write the proxy config by hand.